# GWT "No source code is available for type" when incrementalCompileWarnings flag set to true

Tags: java, maven, gwt, incremental-compiler, gwt-2.7

Our project compiles fine when flag incrementalCompileWarnings isn't set to true (for maven-gwt-plugin). When it's set, there appear several errors like this:

```
Tracing compile failure path for type 'my.module.client.entryPoint.MyModuleEntryPoint'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/path/to/jar.jar!/my/module/client/entryPoint/MyModuleEntryPoint.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 76: No source code is available for type my.module.service.client.SomeClientClass; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

However I have the required line in MyModule.gwt.xml:

```
  <inherits name="my.module.service.client.SomeClient"/>
```

What could cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the file is retrieved from a jar. It could be that the jar is not up to date.

Comment: I've checked inside the jar. All required information is there and up to date.

Comment: Makes sense..otherwise it also wouldn't work without incrementalCompileWarnings